# HMS Reward Ads| Server Side Verification| Callback has no data

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

Integrated Reward ads in gaming application. After watching reward ads Huawei server sends a callback to My server. Server is getting the callback but there is no ads data.
We followed below link for integration.                     https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides-V5/publisher-service-reward-0000001050066917-V5#EN-US_TOPIC_0000001056434869__section145861622124711

What content encoding format for the callback url, i suspect the encoding?

Answer (score 1):

If data and userId are not set, reward grant events can still be reported, but the two parameters will not be present in the server-side callback. If you want to set data and userId, set them before showing the ad and ensure that the encoded URL does not exceed 1024 characters. Failing to meet this requirement can affect server-side verification.

Sign in to HUAWEI Ads Publisher Console, go to My apps, click Add ad unit, select the rewarded ad, and click Next. On the page that is displayed, set the reward type and quantity, click Advanced settings, and set the server-side verification URL. The following figure shows the reward settings.

Set data and userId for a rewarded ad object before requesting a rewarded ad.

```
RewardAd rewardAd = new RewardAd(RewardActivity.this, getString(R.string.ad_id_reward));
RewardVerifyConfig config = new RewardVerifyConfig.Builder().setData("CUSTOM_DATA")
    .setUserId("1234567")
    .build();
rewardAd.setRewardVerifyConfig(config);
...
rewardAd.loadAd(new AdParam.Builder().build(), rewardAdLoadListener);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems UTF-8 format is not supported at the your Server end for given URL.
In document also it is mentioned UTF-8 Content-Encoding  is used to compress the media-type.
For more detail you can check with below reference link:

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides-V5/publisher-service-reward-0000001050066917-V5#EN-US_TOPIC_0000001056434869__section145861622124711

[image]